# How to say "shin splints" in Chinese?

Tags: translation

I would like to know how to say "shin splints" in Chinese.  Shin splints are a fairly common injury for runners.

Please note that shin splints are NOT splints that you put on your shin but rather a pain that occurs along the inner edge of the shin bone ([Wikipedia article here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shin_splints)).

I tried looking up "shin splints", "splints", and "splint" on my Android Pleco app but all I got for definitions was "splint" meaning the same thing as a "cast", or something you put your limb in to support it during recovery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well looks like you should invest in new (Pleco) dictionaries:

> 外胫夹 -*Zhongshan Medical*

&

> [用作单数] 【病理学】 (田径运动员等患的) 外胫炎,外胫酸痛 [1940∼1945] -*21 Century*

Baidu also returns the following:

> 胫前疼痛/外胫夹(Shin splints)

I would go with **外胫夹**